# Test if a method was called without providing parameters

Tags: scala, testing, mockito

I have the following code:

```
class MyClass {

  def someMethods(): Unit = {
    val result1 = method1()
    val result2 = method2(result)     
  }
}
```

No I want to test if method1 and method2 are called, when I run someMethod.

```
class TestMyClass {

  @Test
  def testSomeMethods(): Unit = {
    val myClass = new MyClass()
    val myClassSpy = Mockito.spy(myClass)
    myClassSpy.someMethods()
    verify(myClassSpy).method1()
  }
}
```

For method1 this is working, but method2 needs a parameter, that is provided by method1.
Can I not just do something like **assertTrue(method2.called)**? 
Because I do not want to check the result of the methods, I just want to know if they were called.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, using a spy for that is already a smell, you shouldn't be testing internals of your class like that.

In any case you could do `Mockito.verify(myClassSpy).method2(Mockito.any())` and that would do the trick, but I'd seriously review your design and the motivation behind this test as it really feels like the wrong approach.